# Is it possible to see any answers to a question that were posted before it was closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I posted a question about mocking static methods, which was closed as 'unproductive'.  I'm not sure why (I'll try to improve it) but I'd like to see if anyone answered it before it was closed.  Is this possible?

Comment: If you're talking about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488113/mocking-classes-with-static-methods , there were no answers on it when it was closed. Answers don't do away on closing, as you can see in this other closed question of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146256/understanding-the-construct-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there were any answers on it before it closed, you would still see them.

Closing a question does not delete or hide the answers, it simply prevents anyone from answering the question after the close.